# Simple update of input in React to State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update city, which is already having a default value in state, based on the input from user; but I am getting an error instead. Can someone help me out in this example!

> Also, let me know if there is any better method to do this task. (as I am novice in react and thought this to be the best way to fetch data via (document.getElementById) and then send it to function in component.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Home extends Component {

  state = {
    city: "London"
  }

  updateCity(value){
    this.setState({city: value})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.city}</p>
        <input type="text" id="city" />
        <button onClick={this.updateCity(document.getElementById('city').value)}>Update City</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: Please read the documentation for [form elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html). The `updateCity` function gets executed when the component is rendered. `document.getElementById` is not how to handle inputs in React. Please. read. the. documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use input reference instead of `document.getElementById`. Or you can manage another state variable which update on change of input value.
Use arrow function to access `this` in the function.
I have created a demo for you with input reference, Hope it can help!

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  inputRef = React.createRef();
  state = {
    city: "London"
  }

  updateCity=()=> {
    this.setState({ city: this.inputRef.current.value })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.city}</p>
        <input type="text" ref={this.inputRef}/>
        <button onClick={this.updateCity}>Update City</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In React usually you have 2 ways of referencing/updating values on the **DOM**:

- refs - Uncontrolled Components
- state - Controlled Components

## Using refs

The components that user **refs** for controlling the DOM are also called [Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

In your case, the easiest way is to use **refs** so you don't add complexity:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  inputRef;
  
  state = {
    city: "London"
  }

  updateCity=()=> {
    this.setState({city: this.inputRef.value})
    this.inputRef.value = ""
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.city}</p>
        <input type="text" ref={r => this.inputRef = r}/>
        <button onClick={this.updateCity}>Update City</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

## Using state

These kind of components are the recommended way of controlling componets, and are called [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

In this case you need to add a second property into your state to follow the value of the input, when you add a piece of state as part of a input you need to also set an **onChange** event so it updates on every key stroke. Once the user clicks the button, on the **onSubmit** event you set the other part of the state with the updated one, like this:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    city: "London",
    cityOnInput: ""
  };

  updateCity = () => {
    this.setState({
      city: this.state.cityOnInput,
      cityOnInput: ""
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.city}</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.cityOnInput}
          onChange={e => this.setState({ cityOnInput: e.target.value })}
        />
        <button onClick={this.updateCity}>Update City</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Home/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`updateCity` function needs to bind to the class to set the scope to the class . Currently it is searching on the window object .

Call the below function in the constructor of the class

```
this.updateCity = this.updateCity.bind(this)
```

Comment: This is not the issue. `this.updateCity` will still get executed when the component mounts

Answer (score 0):

At the time of component render the DOM element with id `city` is not created  in the DOM that's why you are getting this error.

Use react `ref` api or access the DOM with `browser native api (not recommended in react)`   in `updateCity` function instead of passing it in the argument.

**Extar note:**

Please bind `this` to 'updateCity' function. When the click event triggered the `this` will not refer to the class it will refer to the event object. So you have to bind `this` . You can achieve this with an arrow Function or with `bind` method.

You can use `bind` in the constructor or in the onClick event.

> Please note Never interact directly with DOM element in react. Always use react apis to interact with DOM.

**Recommended:**

```
 class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    city: "London"
  }
  inputEle = React.createRef();

  updateCity() {
    const value = this.inputEle.current.value;
    this.setState({
      city: value
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.city}</p>
        <input type="text" id="city" ref={this.inputEle} />
        <button onClick={this.updateCity.bind(this)}>Update City</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Not Recommended**

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    city: "London"
  }
  inputEle = React.createRef();

  updateCity() {
    const value = document.getElementById('city').value;
    this.setState({
      city: value
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.city}</p>
        <input type="text" id="city" ref={this.inputEle} />
        <button onClick={this.updateCity.bind(this)}>Update City</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try like this, You just need to add "event",

> onClick={e => this.updateCity(document.getElementById("city").value)}

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    city: "London"
  };
  updateCity(value) {
    this.setState({ city: value });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hi from home,
        <p>{this.state.city}</p>
        <input type="text" id="city" />
        <button onClick={e => this.updateCity(document.getElementById("city").value)}>City2</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/throbbing-dream-nkfpx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)